# Transmitting beacon is not detected by Ranging

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I am working on Ble Project and I have to make my phone into an emitter.  I have succeeded in making my phone emit as a beacon but the problem is that I don't detect it while ranging.  I have used Locate and I find my phone. However, while ranging I find no trace of it. I am really stuck.

I am using [AltBeacon Transmitter](https://github.com/AltBeacon/altbeacon-transmitter-android) for transmitting. I am using [some sample code](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) for ranging using altbeacon.

Comment: This is the part of the code i am using for transmission:                      Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                    .setId1("24ddf411-8cf1-440c-87cd-e368daf9c93e")
                    .setId2("1")
                    .setId3("2")
                    .setManufacturer(0x0000) 
                    .setTxPower(-59).build();
mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);

Comment: You can and should edit your question with this info instead of leaving it in a comment, which allows you to format it as code. Besides, all information required to help you should be on the question, not on another site as per [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you very much ,I have tried to put my code with the question but it did not want to submit so i didn't have a choice so i have decided to put the links. I will retry to put the code with my question.Sorry :)

Comment: My problem is resolved;I have tried many times and I have a problem in the way I was putting my UUID.For example : I was giving 24ddf411-8cf1-440c-87cd-e368daf9c93e as UUID but the real format was: 24ddf4118cf1440c87cde368daf9c93e .Thank You and good day.

Comment: To mark a question as solved, you have to select a "best answer". If you found the solution yourself, post it as an answer and check it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is resolved;I have tried many times and I have a problem in the way I was putting my UUID.For example : I was giving 24ddf411-8cf1-440c-87cd-e368daf9c93e as UUID but the real format was: 24ddf4118cf1440c87cde368daf9c93e .Thank You and good day. –